# Why i am not able to read data countinoulsy from in_voltage0_raw channel in linux ADC read

Tags: linux, adc

Here i pasted my code, the problem i am facing is i can able to read the data but i can't able to read change in data in in_voltage1_raw ,
can you please anyone help me out to how to solve this problem,
Here i pasted my code, the problem i am facing is i can able to read the data but i can't able to read change in data in in_voltage1_raw ,
can you please anyone help me out to how to solve this problem,

Here i pasted my code, the problem i am facing is i can able to read the data but i can't able to read change in data in in_voltage1_raw ,
can you please anyone help me out to how to solve this problem,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<signal.h>

int fd_adc[8];
int fd_adc_p[8];
char buffer[256];

float voltage,current;



void adc_int(void);
void adc_read(void);

int count;


int main(void)
{
   adc_int();

   while(1)
   {
    adc_read();
    usleep(100000);
   }

}


void adc_int(void)
{

   fd_adc[0]=open("/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage1_raw",O_RDWR|O_NDELAY|O_NOCTTY);
   perror("open");

   fcntl(fd_adc[0],F_SETFL,O_ASYNC);

   fd_adc_p[0]=open("/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/power/runtime_enabled",O_RDWR);
   perror("open");
   write(fd_adc_p[0],"1",2);
   


}

void adc_read(void)
{
  int data;
  ioctl(fd_adc[0],FIONREAD,&count);
  if(count>0)
  {  
    read(fd_adc[0],&buffer[0],count);
  }

  data=atof(buffer);
  printf("data %d\n",data);

  if(data<=387)
  {
   voltage=((data/100)-0.1);
  }
  else if((data>=388)&&(data<=775))
  {
   voltage=((data/100)-1.1);
  }

  else if((data>=776)&&(data<=1100))
  {
      voltage=((data/100)-1.0678);
  }

  else if((data>=1101)&&(data<=1397))
  {
      voltage=((data/100)-2.0123);
  }

  else if((data>=1398)&&(data<=1652))
  {
      voltage=((data/100)-3.123);
  }

  else if((data>=1653)&&(data<=1904))
  {
      voltage=((data/100)-3.023);
  }
  else if((data>=1905)&&(data<=2165))
  {
        voltage=((data/100)-4.0197);
  }

  else if((data>=2166)&&(data<=2414))
  {
      voltage=((data/100)-4.5023);
  }

  else if((data>=2415)&&(data<=2655))
  {
      voltage =((data/100)-5.04);
  }





 printf("%f\n",voltage);  
 //close(fd_adc[0]);
  
}


Here i pasted my code, the problem i am facing is i can able to read the data but i can't able to read change in data in in_voltage1_raw , 
can you please anyone help me out to how to solve this problem,
```

Comment: Check result returned by `read()` function. Likely it returns -1 and errno is EAGAIN as data is not ready. You set async mode for opened descriptor so you should use asynchronous notifications. Or remove O_ASYNC and read in blocking mode.

Comment: Hi ...Thanks for your reply, i print the result of read , read is returning 0 and perror("read") is troughing read: bad file descriptor, can you please help me out to solve this issue

Comment: `perror()` makes no sence if `read()` don't indicate error by returning -1. Try to enable ring buffer by echoing buffer length to `/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/length` and echoing 1 `/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable` Also maybe trigger setup is reqired. I don't know what exactly your device and it's driver need to configure.